# Tailwind styling not working in react project

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have installed and innit tailwind in my react project.
This is my tailwind config file:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/projects/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

This is my folder structure:

[image]

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "tailwind",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
    "tailwind": "^4.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.6"
  }
}
```

What is the issue?

Comment: You don't by any chance have it installed as a dev dependency, do you? I've seen that mistake before

Comment: It is in dev dependency. How do I add it in normal dependency?

Comment: Adding my package.json in the question. Please look

Comment: Un install it then reinstall it without the -dev tag

Comment: That needs to be added to `dependencies`, not `devDependencies` since those will not be bundled. You can either manually move it and run `npm` or `yarn` (whichever you're using), but make sure when you add it you're not installing it as a dev dependency

Comment: Any idea why it says to install with -D in the tailwind documentation?

Comment: @AlexK uninstalled, installed without dev tag and restarted using npm. Still the same issue

Comment: Are you adding all of the tailwind directives to your css? That includes base, components, and utilities

Comment: Yes, added in my index.css file. Pretty straight forward set up. Don't know why it isn't wokring

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

in your `app.css` file